# Objective C: http POST request getting Unescaped

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am using a NSMutableURLRequest to send a (synchronous) POST request to a web service.
The request body contains a combination of XML and JSON. Something like :

```
<element>
 <element 2>
 <![CDATA[
  {"jsondata1":{"datafield1":"data1"},
   "jsondata2":"some data"
  }
 ]]>
 </element 2>
</element>
```

**the JSON string has been escaped (Using `escape()` in Javascript)**

When I receive the request at the other end I notice that all escaped characters have been unescaped!!

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? And how can I prevent this?

Here is the code that I'm using to send the request:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://my-webservice.com/something.do"];
NSData *xmlResponseDataSave;
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[xmlRequestString length]];
[req addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *saveData=[xmlRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[req setHTTPBody:saveData];

NSError *error=nil;

NSURLResponse *resp=[[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
xmlResponseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&resp error:&error];
NSString *xmlResponseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Please note: I cannot make any change to the xml or the web service. I can only change the objective c code.

Comment: What sort of "escaping" are you talking about?

Comment: @trojanfoe To be precise, the JSON string is escaped using the javascript  [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) function to encode the special characters.

Comment: Why?  Can't you put pretty much whatever you like within a `CDATA` section?

Comment: @trojanfoe like i said: I have no control over the xml or the web service that is being called. I just need to make sure the escaped characters are not unescaped while being sent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error the only solution that I could come up with is to string used in the request body before sending it (Since it's gonna get unescaped while being sent):

```
xmlRequestString=[xmlRequestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *saveData=[xmlRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Though this is not a fix in the truest sense, just a work around. But it works for me (So far).

I'm still clue less about the root cause of the problem and **I am still looking for a more elegant solution.**